# Encoding apostrophes in java

Tags: java, string

I have a String containing an RSS feed. My problem is that there is an encoding problem with the apostrophes. Here's what my String contains :

```
<entry>
            <title>67â€™s and Wolves trade defencemen</title>
            <summary type="text">The Ottawaâ€™s 67â€™s and Sudbury Wolves swapped defencemen in a trade on Tuesday, with the 67â€™s /summary>
</entry>
```

As you can see, i got this â€™ caracter everywhere, how i can resolve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: THat is a multibyte character (2 bytes that make up 1 character) that is seen as 2 singlebyte characters. Read this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: How are you reading the feed? It looks like you should change the encoding of the reader from whatever it is currently to UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most likely the RSS feed is in UTF8, but you look at it with some other encoding. When creating FileInputStreams or some other streams in Java (but not all), you can specify the encoding that should be used to parse. Try StandardCharsets.UTF8 in Java 7 or 8 to specify the UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to find the encoding of this string. Is it specified somewhere? Once that's accomplished, you can do

```
InputStream in = ...; // open a stream to your RSS feed
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, streamFormat);
```